# Как убрать пробелы в начале каждой строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[![Код][1]][1]

[![Вывод сообщения][2]][2]

Делаю Telegram бота, и когда отсылаю сообщение, в начале каждой строки стоит пробел, как это исправить?

```py
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('<token>')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def describe(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
    '''
    Привет, {}! Я бот "sendbytes".
    Ты можешь отправить мне строку или число,
    а я тебе верну эту(о) строку/число в
    шестнадцатеричном формате.
    '''.format(message.chat.first_name))
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Заместо `Enter` стоит использовать в виде экранирования символов. `\n` - переносит дальнейший текст на следующую строку. Подробнее - https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-literaly-strok.html

Comment: @Aqua, с чего вы взяли, что `\n` внутри обычных кавычке лучше строки с переносами внутри тройных кавычек? Это одно и то же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('<token>')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def describe(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
    '''Привет, {}! Я бот "sendbytes".
Ты можешь отправить мне строку или число,
а я тебе верну эту(о) строку/число в
шестнадцатеричном формате.'''.format(message.chat.first_name))
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог мне.

Answer (score 1):

Пробелы (или табы), которыми Вы делали отступ в начале каждой строчки, являются частью строки, которую вы в дальнейшем отправляете. Неумение пользоваться тройными кавычками. То, что идёт после открывающих тройных кавычек уже сразу идёт текстом. Таким образом, у Вас текст уже начинается с переноса строки. А затем на каждой новой строчке стоят отступы, которые входят в отправляемую строку.
Чтобы получить желаемый Вами результат, стоит написать вызов функции так:

```py
def describe(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
'''Привет, {}! Я бот "sendbytes".
Ты можешь отправить мне строку или число,
а я тебе верну эту(о) строку/число в
шестнадцатеричном формате.'''.format(message.chat.first_name))
```

---

Чтобы увидеть разницу, выполните следующий код:

```py
def orig(): # Ваш вариант
    print(
    '''
    Привет, {}! Я бот "sendbytes".
    Ты можешь отправить мне строку или число,
    а я тебе верну эту(о) строку/число в
    шестнадцатеричном формате.
    ''')


def fixed(): # Исправленное
    print(
'''Привет, {}! Я бот "sendbytes".
Ты можешь отправить мне строку или число,
а я тебе верну эту(о) строку/число в
шестнадцатеричном формате.''')

print("-"*8)
orig()
print("-"*8)
fixed()
print("-"*8)
```

Comment: Я сделал точно так же, как у вас, но результат не изменился.

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще одно решение данной проблемы.

```
def get_text(name, frst_arg, sec_arg):
    some_text = f'{name}'\
    f'\n!!!{frst_arg}!!!' \
    f'\n!!!{sec_arg}_1234567890!!!' \
    '\nend_text!'

    return some_text 

print( get_text('test', 'first_arg', 'second_arg') )

# Такой результат
#test
#!!!first_arg!!!
#!!!second_arg_1234567890!!!
#end_text!
```

Данный вариант должен подойти, поскольку питон склеивает все строки и без оператора "+" поэтому это все одна строка.

Символ "\" дает понять питону что дальше будет продолжение строки и он не выдавая ошибки склеивает все строки в единую строку.

Символ "\n" означает перенос сроки. #ВСЯ СТАВКА НЕ НЕГО. Если телега так и напечатает со знаком "\n", то все даром...

Также можно использовать табуляцию "\t"

Думаю, что этот вариант должен подойти.

Comment: `Поскольку вы НЕ печатаете текст в консоль, Вам не подходят предыдущие варианты.` - не понятно при чем тут консоль. Оба варианта (по сути идентичные) работают, и подходят вопросу.

Comment: Прочитав комментарий  пользователя "Smooth" – "Я сделал точно так же, как у вас, но результат не изменился.", решил, что возможно загвоздка с пробелами возникает через то, что строка выводится в телеге а не с помощью принта (возможно в принте происходит какая-то магия).  Да, соглашусь, высказался некорректно. Пожалуй изменю свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё и вот так:

```
def describe(message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id, (
            'Привет, {}! Я бот "sendbytes".\n'
            'Ты можешь отправить мне строку или число,\n'
            'а я тебе верну эту(о) строку/число в\n'
            'шестнадцатеричном формате.'
        ).format(message.chat.first_name))
```

Переводы строк `\n` нужно добавлять. Также надо учитывать, что если не добавить `\n`, то в конце каждой конкретной строки надо вручную добавлять пробел (при необходимости), т. к. запись выше эквивалентна следующей:

```
'Привет, {}! Я бот "sendbytes".\nТы можешь отправить мне строку или число,\n ...'
```